# I've accidentally deleted the /etc/rc.d/functions folder and functions.d script and turned my Arch Linux machine into a brick

Tags: linux, arch-linux

None of my daemon scripts work now, and the startup process displayed errors. Should I reinstall the OS and start from scratch, or is there a way to recover these files? Is there a way to rebuild the files I deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `functions.d` directory should be empty by default (unless you have added some custom functions there), for the `functions` file try replacing it with [this working copy](http://pastebin.com/KC7bLi01).

I suspect they are the same with each installation.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I copied the functions file and rebooted, and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/rc.d/functions` is a *file*, owned by the **`initscripts`** package.

Boot from an Arch CD, mount your root partition, and use `pacman -Syr /mnt initscripts` to reinstall.

`/etc/rc.d/functions.d/` is a *folder*, empty by default. It's for user-defined functions.

Comment: I must have gotten the file/folder confused earlier, but this makes more sense. However, I used user69175's method since he posted first. Would you recommend reinstalling the `initscripts` package even though everything (seems to be) working properly?

Comment: I just realized that since SSH and networking is running, I could simply use `pacman -S initscripts`. I did so, and everything is back to normal!